# Error in Implementing WS Security web service in WebLogic 10.3

Tags: java

I am trying to develop a JAX WS web service with WS-Security features in WebLogic 10.3.
I have used the ant tasks WSDLC, JWSC and ClientGen to generate skeleton/stub for this web service.

I have two keystores namely WSIdentity.jks and WSTrust.jks which contains the keys and certificates. One of the alias of WSIdentity.jks is "ws02p".

The test client has the following code to invoke the web service:

```
SecureSimpleService service = new SecureSimpleService();
SecureSimplePortType port = service.getSecureSimplePortType();

List credProviders = new ArrayList();
CredentialProvider cp = new ClientBSTCredentialProvider(
    "E:\\workspace\\SecureServiceWL103\\keystores\\WSIdentity.jks",
    "webservice", "ws01p","webservice");

credProviders.add(cp);

string endpointURL="http://localhost:7001/SecureSimpleService/SecureSimpleService";
BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider)port;
Map<String, Object> requestContext = bp.getRequestContext();

requestContext.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endpointURL);
requestContext.put(WSSecurityContext.CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_LIST,credProviders);

requestContext.put(WSSecurityContext.TRUST_MANAGER, new TrustManager() {
    public boolean certificateCallback(X509Certificate[] chain,
    int validateErr) {
        // Put some custom validation code in here.
        // Just return true for now
         return true;
    }
});

SignResponse resp1 = new SignResponse();

***resp1 = port.echoSignOnlyMessage("hello sign");***
System.out.println("Result: " + resp1.getMessage());
```

When I trying to invoke this web servcie using this test client I am getting the error "Invalid signing policy" with the following stack trace:

```
 *[java] weblogic.wsee.security.wss.policy.SecurityPolicyArchitectureException: Invalid signing policy
     [java]  at weblogic.wsee.security.wss.plan.SecurityPolicyBlueprintDesigner.verifyPolicy(SecurityPolicyBlueprintDesigner.java:786)
     [java]  at weblogic.wsee.security.wss.plan.SecurityPolicyBlueprintDesigner.designOutboundBlueprint(SecurityPolicyBlueprintDesigner.java:136)
```

Am I missing any configuration settings in WebLogic admin console or is it do with something else?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error as you. We started using 10.3 and this error started to occur. Previous weblogic versions were fine. I used the wsimport tool from the jdk 1.6 to generate the client side classes. If I run my client outside the weblogic server and just rely on the jdk1.6 implementation, I don't get the excpetion. But when weblogic.jar is on the classpath, the exception is thrown. I realise jdk 1.6 and weblogic have their own jax-ws implementations.

If you junit your client outside weblogic with jdk 1.6 and try different weblogic.jar versions on your classpath, you will probably get different results.

Our web service is one way ssl. The client just needs to trust the host. The server certificate is in our truststore that the jdk and weblogic uses. ie cacerts. No more should be required with regards to security I would have thought.

Using just jdk 1.6 or previous weblogic versions, the following code works fine.

```
TestService test = new TestService();
TestPortType port = test.getTestPort();
((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
        "https://host/test");

((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY,
        "user_name");

((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY,
        "password");

TestRequest request = new TestRequest();
request.setWho("Dan Mad");
TestResult result = port.send(request);
System.out.println("result: "+result.getResult());
```

When weblogic.jar from 10.3 is on the classpath however, the above code falls over with the SecurityPolicyArchitectureException exception. I am not sure what else our client needs to provide. Your client is setting more security related things but I am not sure if this is required for our case. I have lodged a request with Oracle. No luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem in your soap message headers. I recommend you to generate your soap headers on your own. Follow below link to find it out:

http://www.javadb.com/using-a-message-handler-to-alter-the-soap-header-in-a-web-service-client/

you can change the header to get what you want and you can check the desired soap request message format by soapUI application.